# Enqueue and Dequeue using ES6 spread operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I have an array of array "animals" and I want to write two functions enqueue and dequeue on it, using es6 spread syntax. [FIFO]

I want this because this object is in my redux state and I dont want mutations on enqueue and dequeue. Instead I want a new animals object everytime enqueue and dequeue happens.

```
let animals = [[cat][dog][elephant][mouse]]

enqueue(element) 
{ 
   animals = [...animals, element]
}

dequeue()
{
   animals = [???]
}
```

Comment: To avoid Mutations

Comment: This is an object in my redux state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an operator; it's a syntax. And you could use it to implement `dequeue` by doing something like this:

```js
let animals = ["cat", "dog", "elephant", "mouse"];

function enqueue(element) {
    animals = [...animals, element];
}

function dequeue() {
    let element;
    [element, ...animals] = animals;
    return element;
}

console.log(animals);
enqueue("frog");
console.log(animals);
console.log(dequeue());
console.log(animals);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be last-in-first-out and `pop()`?

Comment: The question doesn't specify whether it's a FIFO or LIFO queue; it just says queue - not stack - so I assumed FIFO.

Comment: @LokeshAgrawal I'd suggest to be specific on details in your questions to avoid downvotes in future.

Comment: Thanks @estus for the suggestion, I will make sure to be specific in future. But queue has only one interpretation i.e. FIFO from its definition.

Comment: what if I don't want to return from dequeue(), instead only update animals.

Comment: Then remove the `return element;`

Comment: thats correct, but linter says element is defined but not used.

Comment: Then tell your linter it is wrong and disable its warning.